# While retreiving lines from text area in php except for the last element remaining all elements adding space a end

Tags: php, html, arrays, tags, textarea

Hi friends when am getting lines from text area and print them in for loop except last element all elements are adding spaces dont know why the space is added as I didnot add any space
Here is code

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <textarea name="words" id="words" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="words_submit" value="Submit keywords">
 </form>


<?php
  if(isset($_POST['words_submit']))
 {

 $text = trim($_POST['words']);
 $text = explode ("\n", $text);

  foreach ($text as $line) {
      for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
          echo $line;
      }
    }

}
?>
```

suppose if 2 items in text area are hello,welcome then it showing output as

```
 hello hello hello hello welcomewelcomewelcomewelcome
```

why there are spaces between hello can anyone please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `\r` characters as well during the explode step.

```
if (isset($_POST['words_submit'], $_POST['words'])) {
    $text = explode ("\r\n", trim($_POST['words']));
    foreach ($text as $line) {
        echo str_repeat($line, 4);
    }    
}
```

This assumes the unrendered text is `hello\r\nwelcome`.

In your code, `$text` is holding `hello\r` and `welcome`.

The `\r` is rendered as a whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rtrim() to get rid off spaces

```
foreach ($text as $line) {
      for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
          echo rtrim($line,' ');
      }
    }
```

Hope it helps